# Returning prioritized documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to write an ES searching method that returns records/documents that have `Tickets to the top of the list.  So for example I do a search on 'Smith' and I get 200 results.  I want all results ordered so that those who have tickets appear first.  I have this query working, however whenever I try and sort by first name, the query no longer sorts by those with tickets and first name.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might keep the original sort order (by Tickets)?

Comment: are you trying to sort on a text type field ? what is your ES version ?

Comment: v5.4.2.  Yes, We are trying to sort on a text field

Comment: ES treat upper case and lower case in a different way while sorting . you need to you fields for the first name and tokenize using lowercase and set fielddata true so that you can sort on string. once you update your mapping reindex your data and then appy the sort.

Comment: The values I am sorting on are all UPPER.  Do I need to re-run the indexer so that they're all LOWER?  I would figure using all UPPER should do the trick since  I'm not mixing cases...

Comment: if you are not mixing cases you don't have to re index.